# Objective C: Optimize UIAlertController for multiple uses from every table cell

Tags: objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have a big table and every click should open a UIAlertController. However if I create it every time from scratch, it takes quite a while. But some buttons need an object from the currently clicked cell, so I cannot always use the same UIAlertController. Is there still some way to improve that the AlertController can be reused but only the objects are updated? At the moment I have stuff like this (where planData is the mentioned object).

```
UIAlertAction *editEvent = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"EDIT_EVENT_ACTION_SH", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    FMEditEventViewController *editEventVC = (FMEditEventViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditEventsViewController"];
    editEventVC.selectedEventPlanData = planData;
    [self presentViewController:editEventVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: Are you talking about the UIAlertController or the UIAlertAction? What exactly "takes quite a while"? Please provide more context (didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I assume)

Comment: Exactly, did select row takes a while, or at least until the AlertController is presented. But I assume because it has to be generated every time from scratch

Comment: If the display of the "cell selection" matters, you could simply put all the UIAlertController stuff into an async call to the main thread. This allows the cell to display it's state, and then pops up the alert controller. You might want to provide more code; you only provide the code for the `UIAlertAction` creation, which should almost happen in an instant.

Answer (score 0):

use class function and just call for desired object as I am doing using swift

```
    class func showAlertWithTwoButtons(caller:UIViewController,title: String, message: String,firstButtonTitle:String = MSG_CANCEL ,firstButtonStyle: UIAlertActionStyle = UIAlertActionStyle.cancel , firstButtonHandler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil , secondButtonTitle: String,secondButtonStyle: UIAlertActionStyle = UIAlertActionStyle.cancel , secondButtonHandler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil ) -> Void {


    let alert = UIAlertController(title:title, message:message, preferredStyle: .alert)


    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: firstButtonTitle, style: firstButtonStyle, handler:firstButtonHandler))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: secondButtonTitle, style: secondButtonStyle, handler:secondButtonHandler))

    caller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
}
```

use this idea for objective c

Comment: But how can I pass certain specific objects for these buttons? So you have also to generate every button completely new

Comment: This still creates a new UIAlertController every time the func is called.

Comment: have you used the model for Plan data?

Comment: pass that object to function of alertView it should work